# how to pass in a GDALResampleAlg to GDAL's RasterIO?

Tags: c++, gdal

The the `RasterIO` method has a `GDALResampleAlg` option using the `GDALRasterIOExtraArg` struct:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180622133749/http://www.gdal.org:80/structGDALRasterIOExtraArg.html)

The [GDAL tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) has an example like this for reading data from a raster band:

```
  poBand->RasterIO( GF_Read, Xoffset, Yoffset, nXSize, nYSize,
                    pafScanline, outXSize, outYSize, GDT_Float32,
                    0, 0);
```

and the unused 12th argument from that can take the resampling option within the  `GDALRasterIOExtraArg`.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723222834/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALRasterBand.html#a30786c81246455321e96d73047b8edf1)

How does one write the C++ to actually pass in the option? I can instantiate the option from the constants:

```
 // how to pass this option in to RasterIO?
  GDALResampleAlg eResampleAlg = GRA_NearestNeighbour;
```

But I don't know C++ well enough to see how to actually use it, and I can't find any examples that I can follow enough to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way, there is a macro `INIT_RASTERIO_EXTRA_ARG` that sets up the extra-arg struct, that is listed here:

[Link](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#raster-api#a16efcda82b88e49244dbbf4d5d2157c4)

Then set the `eResampleAlg` property to the appropriate constant. Some of the other extra-arg parameters are needed for certain cases, but that is outside of scope of this question.

```
float *pafScanline;

GDALRasterIOExtraArg psExtraArg;
INIT_RASTERIO_EXTRA_ARG(psExtraArg);
// TODO expose the resampling options to user
psExtraArg.eResampleAlg = GRIORA_NearestNeighbour;
pafScanline = (float *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*outXSize*outYSize);
CPLErr err = poBand->RasterIO( GF_Read, Xoffset, Yoffset, nXSize, nYSize,
                pafScanline, outXSize, outYSize, GDT_Float32,
                0, 0, &psExtraArg);
```

See here for more [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180622133749/http://www.gdal.org:80/structGDALRasterIOExtraArg.html)